# Injecting code into the web page does not work

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, code-injection, userscripts

This is a follow-up to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574231/how-to-dynamically-inject-a-javascript-function) I asked yesterday.

I have a userscript (kind of like GreaseMonkey script, but for Chrome).

The idea is to add a textbox and a button to the page. Then when the user clicks the button, it kicks off a function that does stuff. So I inject the textbox, button and the function into the page, but when the user clicks the button, the Chrome console tells me "Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function".  So obviously it does not see the function I just injected and that is specified in the `onclick` event for the button.

So I have code like this:

```
initialize();

function initialize() { 
    var dropDown = document.getElementById("tstGlobalNavigation_ddlChooseProject"); 

    // add a textbox 
    dropDown.innerHTML = dropDown.innerHTML + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='text' name='txtSearch' style='position:absolute;top:8px;left:800px;width:50px' >";

    // add a button 
    dropDown.innerHTML = dropDown.innerHTML + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='button' name='btnSearch' value='Go' onclick='fn()' style='position:absolute;top:8px;left:860px;width:35px'>";

    addScript("var obj = document.getElementById('txtSearch'); " 
    + "if (obj != null) { " 
    + " var incidentId = document.getElementById('txtSearch').value; " 
    + " var currentURL = location.href; " 
    + " var splitResult = currentURL.split('/'); " 
    + " var projectId = splitResult[4]; " 
    + " location.href = 'http://dev.myApp.com/ProductTeam/' + projectId + '/Incident/' + incidentId + '.aspx'; " 
    + " }" 
    , "fn"); 
}

function addScript(contents, id) { 
    var head, script; 
    head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; 
    script = document.getElementById(id); 
    if(script != undefined) { 
    head.removeChild(script); 
    } 
    script = document.createElement('script'); 
    script.type = 'text/javascript'; 
    script.id = id; 
    script.innerHTML = contents; 
    head.appendChild(script); 
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Where do you bind the event handler?

Comment: this code is not the source of the problem. It would be helpful if you posted the code where you bind the event handler

Comment: @Alex, @Dexter - sorry, somehow the handler got eaten in the copy/paste operation.

Comment: @Brock: this is clearly not a dup.

Comment: @Brock, the dupe you linked to is the same question I specified as being a follow-up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not calling the function you created, you're using the id that you give to the script tag... Try changing the code to

```
addScript("function fn() { var obj = document.getElementById('txtSearch'); " 
    + "if (obj != null) { " 
    + " var incidentId = document.getElementById('txtSearch').value; " 
    + " var currentURL = location.href; " 
    + " var splitResult = currentURL.split('/'); " 
    + " var projectId = splitResult[4]; " 
    + " location.href = 'http://dev.myApp.com/ProductTeam/' + projectId + '/Incident/' + incidentId + '.aspx'; " 
    + " } }" 
    , "fn");
```

and you will have a fn() function that can be called

Comment: Ah, I was wondering why he was assigning an ID to the script tag.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to use the `onclick` element attribute to bind an event handler. These attributes are only parsed when the page is first loaded, at which time the function you're trying to bind as the callback *doesn't exist*.

Avoid binding event handlers in element `on*` attributes whenever possible. This is called writing [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

That said, if you absolutely must stick with using `onclick`, you can bind to a dummy function which does nothing but turn around and call the function that you inject:

```
<button onclick="wrapper()"
```

Where `wrapper` looks something like this:

```
function wrapper() {
    return functionThatWillEventuallyBeInjected();
}
```

Comment: I think you are wrong.  Why?  Because in the chrome console, I get `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function` error when I click the button, which means that the onclick event does fire.

Comment: Right: the `onclick` fires but it's bound to something that isn't defined.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure you can actually create `script` tags on the fly and push content in it.

You could instead create the script tag and modify the src attribute to some JS file:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "path/to/your/javascript.js";
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

If you really need to execute a code stored in a string, maybe you could simply `eval()` it when required!

Comment: You can; I answered the OP's question yesterday and made sure the code works. Perhaps you missed [the demo in my answer](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/eYuak/) (on the earlier question).

Comment: @Matt, I did look at the demo. I think there is some type of qualitative difference between injecting code via MooTools and UserScripts.  I couldn't make it work using plain Javascript and UserScripts, as per example I posted.